Bring to front textbox with image (grouped items) using the picture click code or any other way
I am trying to create a tab effect as per image attached (coloured shapes are actually text boxes with edited points). I am using the codes below which are working fine BUT I would also like to add images to the text boxes. I thought that grouping the images with each respective text box would work (i.e. the code would still apply to all), but it is not. Is there a way please I can have textboxes and images within them, with the option to click on one of the texboxes and bring content and images forward?
Sub picture_click()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
  Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder (msoBringToFront)
End Sub

Sub connect_all()
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
  sh.OnAction = "picture_click"
Next sh
End Sub

As explained above. I used a VBA code I found online that has worked fine bringing forward on a click the textboxes (text) but does not apply to any images I add to the textboxes.
